# randsample + setdiff = original_vector wrong?

Tags: matlab

I have a problem to see what I'm doing wrong, or if the functions are not doing what I think they must do.

The thing is, I have a vector_name with length 142844. I want to make a random sample (of length 4358) and also take the remining numbers like this

```
vector_sample = randsample(1:length(vector_name),4358,true);
contra_vector_sample = setdiff(1:length(vector_name),vector_sample);
```

But if I sum those 2 vectors with

```
length(vector_sample)
length(contra_vector_sample)
```

they don't give 142844, but 142908!

Why it is like that? I thought that setdiff outputs the numbers of vector_name(i) that are not in vector_sample whole vector.

Thanks for all

Comment: Because you are allowing duplicates with `True` option in `randsample`, so the total becomes more than the total elems from original source?

Comment: And what does exactly the `true` statement? I have look in matlab but I don't understand exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `true` for the third input to `randsample` ([referred to in the documentation as `replacement`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html)) to indicate that when a value is drawn from the samples it is replaced (i.e. you can draw the *same value twice*.

> `y = randsample(n,k,replacement)` or `y = randsample(population,k,replacement)` returns a sample taken with replacement if replacement is true, or without replacement if replacement is false. The default is false.

```
randsample(1:4, 3, true)
%   2   1   2
```

You are not expecting this behavior so you'll want to set the `replacement` argument to `false` (or omit it) which will prevent the same value from being drawn twice.

```
randsample(1:4, 3)
%   4   3   1
```

So for your data, we can verify that this yields the results you expect.

```
vector_name = rand(142844, 1);

vector_sample = randsample(1:length(vector_name), 4358);
contra_vector_sample = setdiff(1:length(vector_name), vector_sample);

length(vector_sample)
%   4358

length(contra_vector_sample)
%   138486

length(contra_vector_sample) + length(vector_sample)
%   142844
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't understand the replacement part, but with your example, it is very clear.

Comment: @cloudy_fog Consider marking this as the solution if it solved your problem